# Rounding to 2 decimal places in python gpa calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

For my assignment, I have been asked to create a GPA calculator. They want me to edit my code to make the GPA output always show two decimal places. However, mine doesn't seem to be working! D:

The output only prints to 1 decimal place

here is what I've tried so far, ive also tried str instead of float:

```
gpa = total/num_of_subjects #using this formula the gpa is calculated
gpa = float(round(gpa, 2))

print (gpa) #output gpa
```

Comment: If there is only 1 decimal place to display, that’s all that will be displayed, unless you display a string, such as `print(f'{gpa:.2f}')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the output as a string value with `"{:0.2f}"` format, so your answer will always have 2 decimal digits despite `gpa` value:

```
total, num_of_subjects = 100, 10

gpa = total/num_of_subjects
gpa = float(round(gpa, 2))

print("{:0.2f}".format(gpa))
```

> > 10.00

Comment: you don't need to convert the value of round to float as it already returns a float.

Answer (score 2):

Try formatting it to only display 2 decimals

```
gpa = total / num_of_subjects
print(f"{gpa:.2f}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use int in order for it to round up and not down. The other problem with your code was that you were using num_of_subjects as an input but then trying to divide by it. So if someone entered 3 subjects their gpa would come out at 0.0. Here's how you should fix it:

```
def calculateGPA():

total = float(input("Enter the number of units completed"))

num_of_subjects = float(input("Enter the number of courses taken"))

gpa = total / num_of_subjects

print ("The GPA is", gpa)

if gpa >= 4.0:

print ("Excellent")

elif gpa > 3.5 and <4.0:

print ("Very Good")

else :

print ("Good")

calculateGPA()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from decimal import Decimal


total = 109

num_of_subjects = 33
gpa = total/num_of_subjects #using this formula the gpa is calculated
gpcc= Decimal(gpa)
print(round(gpcc,2))
```

here u have a simplieer solution to the same problem! cheers!